# my material is not showing in the render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I created a material for a scene that I am creating but when I render the object I get a [image]blank cube

I'm using cycle render

[image]

Comment: Whats happening in the compositor? Is there an override Material (in Scene Properties).

Comment: im not using the compositor, i put the material in a new filke juts to see if  there was a problem whit the setting  of the world

Comment: You've got the output of your last _Mix Shader_ node as the color of a _Diffuse Shader_  node. Shaders are closures, functions waiting to be called by the renderer. they don't have a color until called by Cycles. I can't be sure what effect you're looking for, but can be sure it won't work if you try to  interpret the output of a shader as a color in Cycles.

Comment: Robin probably has the answer. However, if there wasnt a composite setup, you wouldn't see the [composite option.](https://i.imgur.com/NXufZca.png)

Comment: its was that thx :D @RobinBetts